# String length through TCP

Tags: c

I'm trying to send an array of 160x120 uint32_t pixel values, which I generate randomly. The first two bytes must have the values (160 and 120) and the data format must be int32_t for both values. How do I somehow pushing those two values of int32_t into the p[0] and p[1] of the uint32_t array ?. The second question is: Does this code send the string length as the first byte of the data?. Before p[0] ?.

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET server_socket, client_socket;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
int c, iResult;
char sendbuf [DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
uint32_t* p;
int32_t* z;
int i;

 // Send uint8_t data to client

p = (uint32_t*)sendbuf;

p[0] = 120; // must be an int32_t value
p[1] = 160; // must be an int32_t value

srand (time(NULL));
for (i = 3; i < 19203; i++)
{
       p[i] = rand() % 4294967295; //range 0-4294967294 */
       printf("%d\n", p[i]);
}
iResult = send(client_socket, sendbuf, (int32_t)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
return 0;

if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
{
    printf("Send failed. Error Code : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    iResult = 1;
}
else
{
    printf("Bytes Sent: %d\n", iResult);
    iResult = 0;
}

// shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
if (shutdown(client_socket, SD_SEND) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
{
    printf("Shutdown failed. Error Code : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    iResult = 1;
}

closesocket(client_socket);
WSACleanup();

return iResult;
}
```

Comment: No. It sends what's in the buffer, up to the length you specify.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `strlen(sendbuf)` in

```
iResult = send(client_socket, sendbuf, (int32_t)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
```

calculate the size appropriately

```
//         number of pixels + int size + 2 ints for p[0] and p[1]
int size = 160*120*sizeof(uint32_t) + 2 *sizeof(uint32_t);
iResult = send(client_socket, sendbuf, size, 0);
```

Also make sure `DEFAULT_BUFLEN` is equal to more than `size`. If you want you can define `DEFAULT_BUFLEN` as that.

Answer (score 0):

1 you should convert the content you want to send in Big-Endian

2 . it will not, the server recieve what the client send